# Caling upon the smooth all attribute in maya using python or MEL

Tags: maya, smoothing

I am trying to script a setup where  the map borders is set to something specific after smoothing the geo in the viewport. I don't know how to call upon that attribute or change it.
[image]

It's under smooth mesh - extra controls in the GEOShape of the mesh.

Any ideas?

Mel or Python... I dont care, I just need to know how to reach these? :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open up the **Script Editor**, and turn on **History > Echo All Commands**

Also open the **Window > General Editors > Attribute Spreadsheet**.

From the *All* tab, find *Keep Map Borders*.

As you change the radio button between *Do not smooth*, *Smooth internal*, and *Smooth all*, you'll see the value in the Attribute Spreadsheet change between *All*, *Internal*, and *None*.

Type *All* in the Attribute Spreadsheet, and look over at the Script Editor. You should see this line:

```
setAttr "pCubeShape1.keepMapBorders" 2;
```

That is the MEL command that sets *Map Borders* to *Do not smooth*